# How to split a list into 2 digit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this:
`a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

And I want to make it into this:
`a = ['ab','cd','ef']`

I tried this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if round(i/2) > len(a):
        break
    c = (a[(i*2)-1])+(a[i*2])
    c_list.append(c)
```

But it didn't work, and I felt it wasn't the best way to approach it.

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Does this work for ya? [a[i]+a[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pair_up(a):
    return [a[i]+a[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
print(pair_up(a))
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist correct. My bad. I forgot to change that when I was changing a simple for loop to list comprehension. If you refer my earlier comment on the question, it has the correct meniton.